# May I know what went wrong here ? I tried several times , could not get pounds side right

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
weight = input("Weight: ")
unit = input("(L)ps or (K)g: ")

if unit == "K":
    V = Pounds = int(weight) * 2.20462
else :
    V = Kilograms = int(weight) / 0.45


print("Your weight is " + str(V) + unit)
```

Comment: To get from pounds to kilograms you need to multiply the amount in pounds by 0.45, not divide it (or you can divide it by 2.20462 instead).

Comment: By the way, you display the original unit in the `print` function instead of the converted ony so the printed value and unit don't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use float instead of int and change the end units. On the other hand, you have an error in the conversion from Lb to Kg, you need to multiply by 0.45 or divide by 2.20462.

```
weight = input("Weight: ")
unit = input("Type L (for Lb) or K (for Kg): ")

if unit == "K":
    V = float(weight) * 2.20462
    new_unit = "Lb"

else :
    V = float(weight) / 2.20462
    #analogously: V = float(weight) * 0.4535
    new_unit = "Kg"

print("Your weight is {} {}".format(V, new_unit))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
weight = input("What's your current Weight: ")

unit = input("Which unit it is currently of -  (L)ps or (K)g: ")

if unit == "K":
    print("Your weight in Kg is " + weight + unit)
    V = int(weight) * 2.20462
    print("Your weight in Pound (LBS) is " + str(V) + unit)
    exit;
else:
    print("Your weight in (Pound) LBS is " + weight + unit)
    V = int(weight) / 2.205
    print("Your weight in Kg is :" + str(V) + unit)
    exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def kgConvertor(kgs):
    pound = kgs * 2.2
    return float(pound)

kgs = float(input("How many kgs? "))
pound = kgConvertor(kgs)
print('The amount of kgs you entered is {}. '\
      'This is {} in pound.'.format(kgs, pound))
```